# How I can fix a bug of "screen lock app" not recognizing that I entered the password on android?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, huawei-map-kit

When I enter the password on my phone it works but all apps isn't working.. Whenever I click on any app it says "Preparing apps.. try again in a moment" and that's because there is a bug in the system.. My phone is not recognizing that I already entered the password because in notifications they write "some features is disabled for security" as you can see in the picture it's still requesting to unlock the phone even when I already unlocked it

All apps in my phone is not working expect settings and optimizer

["some features is disabled for security"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuEvZ.jpg)

["Preparing apps.. try again in a moment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx97j.png)

Please Help me to fix this issue without erasing my data or reset factory

and I have alot of videos of my issue If there is any method to share it with you just tell me if that will help

The full story of the cause of this issue:

My phone was always filling up the storage without downloading anything or doing any update! I don't know why and always when I free up space.. my phone take alot of mega bytes or sometimes giga bytes again (especially when I put it on charger mostly it took alot of mega bytes for nothing) so someday I saw it filling up the space again so I let it be full and then restart it then my phone to return some of the space it took before (this method works fine with me for two years), then when I did it this time it give me back a 300-500 mega bytes but the performance of my phone was very bad and it's fine all I have to do is to restart again as usual.. I restart it again and I got this issue after restart.. since that day my apps isn't working.. I tried to delete apps from settings and I have free up more than 1 GB but it still the same nothing changed!

The solutions that I've tried:

-Restart
-Free up space more than 1 GB by uninstalling apps from settings
-Trying to reach out my files from PC by usb cable but it show me nothing I think because it dealing with my phone as it's locked
-Trying backup by HiSuite but it's not working
-Trying to disable password from settings but it's not working, It's crashing from settings when I try
-Trying to "Reset all settings" but it's not working and crashing when I try
-Trying to "uninstall updates" of google play services but I failed
-Trying to "Disable" google play services but I failed
-Trying to deactivate "Screen lock service" from "Device administrators" in the settings but I failed
-Trying to uninstall last updates of all google apps (expect google play services) but It does not make sense

and alot of other solutions but still can't fix it

Note: I can make another user in my phone from setting and the second user is working fine without issues but I don't think that will help me to fix the admin user

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing same ,it's like you just typed everything I've been experiencing since yesterday.Interesting enough ,my y9 file manager opens but the phones storage is disabled so I can access it to free any more space. I'm really looking forward to the answer as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).